# Scipy Optimization Solution for Multivariable equation

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, numerical-methods

I have a formula here to calculate the volume.

```
def VolCalc(H,L,R,V):

   return L * ((math.acos((R - H)/R) * R**2) - ((R - H)* math.sqrt((2 * R * H) - H**2)))  # Volume
```

However, I have been given the value of the volume (V) and from this the height (H) must be calculated. The value of Radius (R) and Length (L) is known.

This requires a numerical approximation solution and need to know which Scipy optimisation tool must be used. I've looked myself and struggling to find the correct one.

I appreciate any help with this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).
And setup this up as a minimisation problem where you are looking to find the minimum of a scalar function:

```
def target(H):
    return abs(V - (L * ((math.acos((R - H)/R) * R**2) - ((R - H)* math.sqrt((2 * R * H) - H**2)))))
```

where you need to define the values of `V`, `R` and `L`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this ,really appreciate it as it solved my issue.